# Draw array of VBOs in OpenGL ES

Tags: c++, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I have an array of Vertex Array Objects, that each contain a VBO reference, and and array of matrices, of the same size, such as:

unsigned int vaoArray[128];
matrix_t matrixArray[128];

rather than

```
for (i = 0; i < 128; i++)
{
    glBindVertexArray(vaoArray[i]);
    glUniformMatrix4fv(U_MVP_MATRIX_SLOT, 1, GL_FALSE, &matrixArray[i]);
    glDrawArrays(BGL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, 4);
}
```

Is there a way I can push the entire array of VAOs and matrices to the GPU at once? Maybe using the instancing extension somehow?

I can't combine them all in one VAO/VBO, because the combination can change (this is drawing text, with each character having its own VAO/VBO combo).

And yes, I realize this all involves using ES 2.0 extensions. That's OK.

BTW, All of the VAOs for each character are identical except for the VBO id, if that helps.

Comment: They are already on the GPU, what you have in your vaoArray are buffer indices. Since you create 128 buffers you will have 128 unique indices and with binding all you tell the GPU is which one to use. Since you said you can not group it into one, this must be the smallest operation possible to tell the GPU which buffer to use by giving it the ID of the buffer... So I'd say try to restructure this so you CAN pas it as a single buffer, note that buffer data can be changed during runtime.

Comment: At that point don't use VAOs. I think I mis-understand but if you have 128 VBOs on an ES, that is quite a stretch